# I try to make a search on laravel but it doesn't work

Tags: php, search, laravel

```
Route::controller('product', 'ProductController');
```

Here is my code in ProductController.

```
public function getData($search=null)
{
    if($search == null){
        $products = Prod::paginate($limit = 10)->toJson();
        return $products;
    }else{
        $products = Prod::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
                    ->paginate(10)
                    ->toJson();
        return $products;
    }

}
```

And then I try to preview the result but this is what I get.

When I try /project/public/product/data?search=12

```
{"total":72,"per_page":10,"current_page":1,"last_page":8,"from":1,"to":10,"data":[
{"id":148,"name":"tester28","price":1250,"brand_id":5,"category_id":5,"availability":1,"product_pic_id":5,"created_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14","updated_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14"},
{"id":149,"name":"tester29","price":1371,"brand_id":1,"category_id":6,"availability":1,"product_pic_id":3,"created_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14","updated_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14"},
{"id":150,"name":"tester30","price":1351,"brand_id":4,"category_id":5,"availability":1,"product_pic_id":1,"created_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14","updated_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14"},
{"id":151,"name":"tester31","price":374,"brand_id":7,"category_id":8,"availability":1,"product_pic_id":2,"created_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14","updated_at":"2014-03-09 08:54:53"},{"id":152,"name":"tester32","price":1974,"brand_id":9,"category_id":4,"availability":1,"product_pic_id":2,"created_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14","updated_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14"},
{"id":153,"name":"tester33","price":2435,"brand_id":3,"category_id":8,"availability":1,"product_pic_id":1,"created_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14","updated_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14"},
{"id":154,"name":"tester34","price":2392,"brand_id":8,"category_id":9,"availability":1,"product_pic_id":6,"created_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14","updated_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14"},
{"id":155,"name":"tester35","price":1029,"brand_id":6,"category_id":3,"availability":1,"product_pic_id":7,"created_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14","updated_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14"},
{"id":156,"name":"tester36","price":1882,"brand_id":7,"category_id":8,"availability":1,"product_pic_id":10,"created_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14","updated_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14"},
{"id":157,"name":"tester37","price":1233,"brand_id":4,"category_id":10,"availability":1,"product_pic_id":6,"created_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14","updated_at":"2014-03-09 05:31:14"}]}
```

I don't know why they aren't filtered. Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is mainly that $search does not contain what you think it does.  The parameter on your controller will only be filled if you have a route which tells it to use part of the URL as a parameter instead, for example:

```
Route::get('users/view/{id}', ['uses' => 'MyController@MyAction']);
```

So, in your controller you should instead simply look for the input parameters.

```
public function getData()
{
    $search = Input::get('search');
    if(!$search)
    {
        $products = Prod::paginate($limit = 10)->toJson();
        return $products;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $products = Prod::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->paginate(10)
                ->toJson();
        return $products;
    }
}
```